# "Backups" are taking up over 60 G on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, storage

Do I need to keep these backups as I use a Lacie external drive to backup? How do I get rid of them on my computer?

Comment: Time Machine will clear out backups on demand - so you don't need to manage it - just use the space. Perhaps there's more detail on what specifically you are using or seeing to determine "backup" files are taking 60 GB?

Answer (score 2):

*NB: For the purpose of this answer, I will assume you are using Time Machine.*

No, these are Time Machine's "Mobile Backups". You can disable them by running, from `Terminal.app`: (you may be prompted for your password)

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal    # disables local backups
```

and if the above command didn't remove the backups after a while, from `Terminal.app`: (you may be prompted for your password)

```
sudo rm -rf /Volumes/MobileBackups/Computer/*    # removes the large backup directory
```

Time Machine keeps local backups on your computer as indicated in its preference pane:

[image]

> Local snapshots as space permits

Although these local snapshots are deleted automatically, they can be responsible (and they are) for consuming a lot of disk space.

Comment: Time machine doesn't prevent you from saving other files - so in that sense it doesn't consume or block anything from being stored. The system just delays deletion of changed files if you are not otherwise using the space. It's a win-win in my book other than people need to learn this one tidbit when interpreting "free" space and what the backup category in System Information denotes.

Comment: @bmike that is true, but for the most part, we tend to panic when we see directories amassing such large sizes. Indeed, what you say is true, but most people (including me until a few months ago when I began tinkering with TM) wouldn't know about it.